# An other way to say hot question?

Tags: word-request, american-english, synonyms

Well, I'm curious to know how to say a hot question in other ways. By means of hot I want to say important evolving question...

Secondly, I used word "useful" "fruitful", I want synonyms for it. Kindly don't mention google search I already did that and found these words (below) But I want a unique word like futile for useless. Thanks in advance

beneficial, advantageous, helpful, worthwhile, profitable, gainful, rewarding, productive, constructive, effective, efficacious, valuable, fruitful

Comment: This seems like two separate questions, please split them out into different posts. Please can you also give more context to both questions

Comment: What kind of audience do you have for these words?  What you'd say to a group of teenagers is different to what you'd say to a reporter from a newspaper.

Comment: @jonathanjo I'm going to talk with graduate students so it is mostly based on academic conversation.

Comment: I'd echo what @jonathanjo said, and add that context is important. The best synonym for "useful" depends on how it is being used, especially since you've already shown and rejected several suggestions via Google. Can you give examples? Also, if you're going to edit the question so as to add such examples, then I agree with Bee in that it would be better done as two questions -- one for "hot" and one for "useful". Oh! I see Bee also asked about context, so...yeah...great minds an' all that! :-)

Comment: You have to explain why none of the words you've found meet your criteria. Why you considered them and rejected them. We have no idea why you think any of them is wrong for your purpose. Also, both *futile* and *useless* seem to be the opposite of what you're looking for, so it's confusing that you mention those two. (The opposite of *useless*, which you appear to like otherwise, is **useful**, but you've ruled it out for some reason that you haven't stated.) Note that this site isn't just about throwing out an endless list of synonyms. We need to target a *specific* single-word answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you want here; to stimulate your audience or just be more original in your approach, but I would suggest

for "Hot" either

**Juicy** or **Captivating**

Whilst for "useful" I would suggest

**Fertile** or **Gainful**

All can be reference using the Cambridge English Dictionary

Hopefully your students will not be using this site or their research might be as consummate as yours.

Comment: thanks for your answer.

Comment: For an important question you can say "crucial question".